# html - get text color using python selenium?

Tags: python, html, selenium

Anyone know how to get the text color for both "office" and "room"?
office_color = "#FD7C04"
room_color = "green"

HTML code:

```
<tr style="background-color:#999" id="tagging">
    <td><b style="white-space: nowrap;">　tag_table</b></td>
        <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span class="big" style="font-size:24px; font-weight:700; color: #FD7C04">office</span></td>
    <td style="text-align:center;">
            <span class="big" style="font-size:24px; font-weight:700; color: green" id="rigan">room</span></td>
</tr>
```

Answer (score 0):

First, get the element you want to extract your atribute from, in this case the *span*. You choose your prefered [method](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io/locating-elements.html) for that. One of them is:

```
selector="body > span:nth-child(2)"
element1=driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
element2=driver.find_element_by_id("#rigan")
```

One way to get this is opening the html on your browser, right click on the element and "copy selector" to get a css selector.
Then get the atribute from the elements:

```
color1=element1.get_attribute("color")
color2=element2.get_attribute("color")
```

Comment: Thanks Pablo, I new to Python. Abit confuse for me. What should I edit to the code from html?

Comment: No need to modify anything in the html. 
You just need a "selector" to get the element you want in python, one way to find the selector more easily is with your browser: https://amasty.com/knowledge-base/product-labels-find-css-selector.html
You could just use the ones I gave you too.

Comment: I got the error below:

Comment: element1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)
Exception in Tkinter callback
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python310\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1921, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\FengShui\fshui.py", line 546, in print_click
    element1 = driver.find_element_by_css_selector(selector)

Comment: File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\SocialMedia\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 809, in find_element_by_css_selector
    return self.find_element(by=By.CSS_SELECTOR, value=css_selector)
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\SocialMedia\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 1248, in find_element
    return self.execute(Command.FIND_ELEMENT, {

Comment: File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\SocialMedia\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\webdriver.py", line 425, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "C:\Users\Al PC\PycharmProjects\SocialMedia\venv\lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\remote\errorhandler.py", line 247, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.NoSuchElementException: Message: no such element: Unable to locate element: {"method":"css selector","selector":"body > span:nth-child(2)"}
  (Session info: chrome=101.0.4951.54)

Comment: Stacktrace:
Backtrace:
 Ordinal0 [0x003BB8F3+2406643]
 Ordinal0 [0x0034AF31+1945393]
 Ordinal0 [0x0023C748+837448]
 Ordinal0 [0x002692E0+1020640]
 Ordinal0 [0x0026957B+1021307]
 Ordinal0 [0x00296372+1205106]
 Ordinal0 [0x002842C4+1131204]
 Ordinal0 [0x00294682+1197698]
 Ordinal0 [0x00284096+1130646]
 Ordinal0 [0x0025E636+976438]

Comment: Ordinal0 [0x0025F546+980294]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00629612+2498066]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x0061C920+2445600]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00454F2A+579370]
 GetHandleVerifier [0x00453D36+574774]
 Ordinal0 [0x00351C0B+1973259]
 Ordinal0 [0x00356688+1992328]
 Ordinal0 [0x00356775+1992565]
 Ordinal0 [0x0035F8D1+2029777]
 BaseThreadInitThunk [0x769DFA29+25]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F37A7E+286]
 RtlGetAppContainerNamedObjectPath [0x76F37A4E+238]

Comment: You know how what is the error?